# storing xml entries using xsl

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have this code which avoids my webpage from running. I get an error regarding the line which tries to retrieve data from xml file and save it into gnSearchSettings.gnStores.

```
 <xsl:if test="$angularApp = 'gn_search'">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var module = angular.module('gn_search');
    module.config(['gnViewerSettings', 'gnGlobalSettings','gnSearchSettings',
    function(gnViewerSettings, gnGlobalSettings, gnSearchSettings) {
    <xsl:if test="$owsContext">
      gnViewerSettings.owsContext = '<xsl:value-of select="$owsContext"/>';
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$wmsUrl and $layerName">
      gnViewerSettings.wmsUrl = '<xsl:value-of select="$wmsUrl"/>';
      gnViewerSettings.layerName = '<xsl:value-of select="$layerName"/>';
      gnViewerSettings.layerGroup = '<xsl:value-of select="$layerGroup"/>';
    </xsl:if>
    gnViewerSettings.mapConfig = <xsl:value-of select="$mapConfig"/>;
    gnGlobalSettings.isMapViewerEnabled = <xsl:value-of select="$isMapViewerEnabled"/>;
    gnViewerSettings.bingKey = '<xsl:value-of select="$bingKey"/>';
    gnSearchSettings.gnStores = [<xsl:apply-templates select="/root/gui/schemas/iso19139/codelists/codelist[@name='gmd:MD_TopicCategoryCode']/entry" mode="js-translations-topicCat"/>];

    }]);
  </script>
</xsl:if>
```

Actually, I have several xml files for different languages. Here is a part of one of my xml files called codelists.xml:

```
<codelist name="gmd:MD_TopicCategoryCode">
<entry>
  <code>farming</code>
  <label>Farming</label>
  <description>Rearing of animals and/or cultivation of plants. Examples: agriculture,
    irrigation, aquaculture, plantations, herding, pests and diseases affecting crops and
    livestock
  </description>
</entry>
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<entry>
  <code>biota</code>
  <label>Biota</label>
  <description>Flora and/or fauna in natural environment. Examples: wildlife, vegetation,
    biological sciences, ecology, wilderness, sealife, wetlands, habitat
  </description>
</entry>
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<entry>
  <code>boundaries</code>
  <label>Boundaries</label>
  <description>Legal land descriptions. Examples: political and administrative
    boundaries
  </description>
</entry>
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<entry>
  <code>climatologyMeteorologyAtmosphere</code>
  <label>Climatology, meteorology, atmosphere</label>
  <description>Processes and phenomena of the atmosphere. Examples: cloud cover, weather,
    climate, atmospheric conditions, climate change, precipitation
  </description>
</entry>
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<entry>
  <code>economy</code>
  <label>Economy</label>
  <description>Economic activities, conditions and employment. Examples: production, labour,
    revenue, commerce, industry, tourism and ecotourism, forestry, fisheries, commercial or
    subsistence hunting, exploration and exploitation of resources such as minerals, oil and
    gas
  </description>
</entry></codelist>
```

And a xsl template:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="js-translations">
"<xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>":"<xsl:value-of
select="normalize-space(translate(.,'&quot;', '`'))"/>"
<xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
```

I get this error:"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" on the highlighted part of the following image when I look at the inspect webtool of chrome. Actually, what you see in this image is the retrieved data from my XML.
How should I solve the problem? 
      [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2kv1.png)

Comment: Moreover, I tried to write the gnSearchSettings.gnStores line using different syntax such as: { }, { [ ] },'  ', {' '} . Non of them works.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the template with mode "js-translations-topicCat" that matches "entry" as this is where your problem probably lies. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tim, I added a part of my xml file to the question. I think the part mode = "js-translations-topicCat" is regarding several xml files for several languages. This is a part of code which is written before and I am adding something to it and debugging it.

Comment: It is really the template in the XSLT, with mode "js-translations-topicCat" that needs to be shown. Thank you.

Comment: I just found a template with mode "js-translations", I add it to question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You really need to find the template with mode "js-translations-topicCat", to match the mode used in the `xsl:apply-templates` in your first XSLT snippet. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Tim, I did not find that. Actually, I am using an opensource system and I want to change it somehow. Its a big system and the developers told me to add this piece of code to achieve my functionality. I cant find this template in my files. How related is the mode? When you see the debug in the picture, the query is calculated but is has an unexpectted identifier. So, it seems that there is no problem with the calculation od query.